# How can I create dynamic column names in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of numerical columns `[NumColumns]` and I want to Bin all of them but I also want to keep the original value in the data frame as well so I don't want the values simply replaced. How can I do that?

I tried this(which works to replace) -

```
data[NumColumns] = pd.cut(data[NumColumns], bins=[0,30,70,100], labels=["Low", "Mid", "High"])
```

Instead of replacing, I'm hoping it would add '_bin' to the end so I would end up with something like value_bin, revenue_bin, age_bin, etc..

I'm not sure how to do this as I have to declare this on the left-hand side. I'm wondering if there is a common way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simpliest is use `f-string`s:

```
for c in NumColumns:
    data[f'{c}_bin'] = pd.cut(data[c], bins=[0,30,70,100], labels=["Low", "Mid", "High"])
```